# How to log messages from a pam module?

Tags: authentication, pam

The problem I am trying to solve is that I want to know if a certain PAM config file is being used or not.
The latest version of IBM MQ (V8) provides a PAM file /etc/pam.d/ibmmq.  We're troubleshooting authtentication problems and I want to know if this file is being used or not.

I thought I should be able to use [pam_echo](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_echo.html) for this but I misunderstood that module's purpose.  `pam_echo` will display the contents of the file specified to the user.  This is not what I want I want to somehow log that a module is being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following solution that works but I'm open for other suggestions.

[pam_exec](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) can be used to call external commands.  I'm using a very simple form to print a message to a log file.

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    optional pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/ibmmq.log /usr/bin/echo "ibmmq auth"
auth    include system-auth
account optional pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/ibmmq.log /usr/bin/echo "ibmmq account"
account include system-auth
```

Note that the `log=` option needs to be specified before the command and that you need to fully qualify the paths.